# Laravel 4.2. Как получить модель в виде массива

Tags: php, orm, laravel, eloquent

Как получить модель в виде массива, ключами которого, будут значения столбца id?

Answer (score 1):

Если имеется ввиду получить коллекцию из моделей, ключами которой будут id, то скорее так
Entites::all()->keyBy('id');

Answer (score -3):

```
$entity = Entity::first();
$entity->toArray();
```

справедливо и для коллекций результата:

```
$entities = Entity::all();
$entities->toArray();
```

Comment: StackOverflow не поддерживает форматирование с помощью трёх бектиков, только с помощью отступов.